# Return from block - from method called within block?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define a DSL where rules (for the sake of this example, the rules define whether something is "good" or "bad") are specified in a block in Ruby. The following is a (grossly simplified) version of what I want to do:

```
def test_block
  # Lots of other code
  is_good = yield   # ... should give me true or false
  # Lots of other code
end

test_block do
  good if some_condition
  good if some_other_condition
  bad
end
```

Is there any way I can define methods `good` and `bad` that make the block break? In the above example, I want to:

- check if **some_condition** is true, and if it is, break out of the block and have it return true
- check if **some_other_condition** is true, and if it is, break out of the block and have it return true
- return false from the block unconditionally if we're still in it

i.e. I want to make the above code behave as if I had written the block like so:

```
result = test_block do
  break true if some_condition
  break true if some_other_condition
  break false
end
```

Putting `break` in the definition of the good/bad method obviously doesn't work. Is there some other way of achieving my desired result or should I think about some entirely different way of going about this?

Comment: Very relevant: http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could raise an exception in the block and catch that exception.

```
module Tester
  class Breaker < Exception; end
  class GoodBreak < Breaker; end
  class BaadBreak < Breaker; end
end

def test_block(name)
  begin
    yield
  rescue Tester::Breaker=>e
    case e
      when Tester::GoodBreak then puts "All is well with #{name}"
      when Tester::BaadBreak then puts "BAD STUFF WITH #{name}"
      else raise
    end
  end
end

def good; raise Tester::GoodBreak; end
def bad;  raise Tester::BaadBreak; end

test_block('early out') do
  good if true
  good if puts("NEVER SEE THIS") || true
  bad
end

test_block('simple pass') do
  good if false
  good if puts("SEE THIS FROM PASS TEST") || true
  bad
end

test_block('final fail') do
  good if false
  good if puts("SEE THIS BUT PUTS IS NIL")
  bad
end

#=> All is well with early out
#=> SEE THIS FROM PASS TEST
#=> All is well with simple pass
#=> SEE THIS BUT PUTS IS NIL
#=> BAD STUFF WITH final fail
```

Here's another example using `throw/catch` (thanks @jleedev!) instead of `raise/rescue` (updated to pass a return value along):

```
def test_block(name)
  result = catch(:good){ catch(:bad){ yield } }
  puts "Testing #{name} yielded '#{result}'", ""
end

def good; throw :good, :good; end
def bad;  throw :bad,  :bad;  end

test_block('early out') do
  good if true
  good if puts("NEVER SEE THIS") || true
  bad
end

test_block('simple pass') do
  good if false
  good if puts("SEE THIS FROM PASS TEST") || true
  bad
end

test_block('final fail') do
  good if false
  good if puts("SEE THIS BUT PUTS IS NIL")
  bad
end

#=> Testing early out yielded 'good'
#=> 
#=> SEE THIS FROM PASS TEST
#=> Testing simple pass yielded 'good'
#=> 
#=> SEE THIS BUT PUTS IS NIL
#=> Testing final fail yielded 'bad'
```

Comment: This might be a better application of `throw`/`catch`, since you’re using them for flow control. (Or call/cc. Heh.)

Comment: @jleedev Right you are! It's been too long since I used those. Here is [introductory documentation on using throw/catch](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html%23catchandthrow) from the free first edition of Programming Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @Phrogz and @jleedev - I thought about using raise but kinda scared away from the thought after a lifetime of being told that exceptions are for "very bad situations"(tm) only ;) 

But the `throw`/`catch` way of doing it feels a lot less wrong!